# No idea why tcpClient isn't working for me

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I've tried checking the server:port with telnet and I'm getting the expected results. So either `writer.Write()` or `reader.ReadLine()` isn't working cause I get nothing from the server.

```
TcpClient socket = new TcpClient(hostname, port);

if (!socket.Connected) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!");
    return;
}

TextReader reader = new StreamReader(socket.GetStream());
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(socket.GetStream());

writer.Write("PING");
writer.Flush();

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.WriteLine("done");
```

EDIT: I might have found the issue. This code was based off examples I found on the web. I tried another irc server: open.ircnet.net:6669 and I got a response:

`:openirc.snt.utwente.nl 020 * :Please wait while we process your connection.`

It seems as if I probably need to run the reader in a Thread so it can just constantly wait for a response. However it does seem weird that the program got caught on the `while` loop without ever printing `done` to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide further details. I'm just going to assume that because you can easily telnet to the server using the same port your problem lies in the evaluation of the `Connected` property...

```
if (!socket.Connected) {
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect!");
    return;
}
```

this is wrong because Microsoft clearly specifies in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected(v=vs.110).aspx) that the `Connected` property is not reliable

> Because the Connected property only reflects the state of the connection as of the most recent operation, you should attempt to send or receive a message to determine the current state. After the message send fails, this property no longer returns true. Note that this behavior is by design. You cannot reliably test the state of the connection because, in the time between the test and a send/receive, the connection could have been lost. Your code should assume the socket is connected, and gracefully handle failed transmissions.

That said, you should not use this property to determine the state of the connection. Needless to say that using this property to control the flow of your console app will result in unexpected results.

#### Suggestion

1. Remove the evaluation of the `Connected` property
2. Wrap your `GetStream` and `Write` method calls in a try/catch block to handle network communication errors

Comment: The program never ended early cause it wasn't "connected" so the `Connected` property always returned as true. And the whole thing is wrapped in a try/catch. Even if i take out the evaluation that won't affect the fact that I can't read from the tcpclient.

Comment: Never the less, I tried your suggestions. No change.

Answer (score 0):

`reader.ReadLine()` will just wait for any data to arrive. If no data arrive, it seems to hang. That's a feature of tcp (I don't like it either). You need to find out how the end of the message is defined and stop based on that end criterion. Be careful, the end of message identifier may be split into two or more lines...

Comment: It's an irc server so I want it to loop as long as the client is connected. I put the `reader.ReadLine()` into a separate thread and I still don't get any of the server's responses coming through.

Answer (score 0):

RFC for ping says that the server may not respond to it & such connections has to be closed after a time. Please check the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459#section-4.6.2